Blender 3.6 Python API renders black as 1
I'm trying to use blender 3.6 Python API to render normalized depth map of single object. To remove the background, I use compositor nodes 'less_than' and 'multiply' as shown below:

The output settings are:

file_format:PNG
color_mode:BW
color_depth:16
compression：0%

However, outputs in Blender and its Python API are different:

Blender:



Blender Python API:


Python code:
import bpy
import bpy.ops as ops
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from math import pi,sin,cos,tan
import os
Objects=bpy.data.objects
Scene=bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
bpy.data.worlds['World'].node_tree.nodes['Background'].inputs[0].default_value=[1,1,1,1]
Engines=['BLENDER_WORKBENCH' ,'BLENDER_EEVEE', 'CYCLES']

Scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_z=True

def deleteAllObjects():
"""
Deletes all objects in the current scene

deleteListObjects = ['MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'META', 'FONT', 'HAIR', 'POINTCLOUD', 'VOLUME', 'GPENCIL',
                     'ARMATURE', 'LATTICE', 'EMPTY', 'LIGHT', 'LIGHT_PROBE', 'CAMERA', 'SPEAKER']
"""
deleteListObjects = ['MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'META', 'FONT', 'HAIR', 'POINTCLOUD', 'VOLUME', 'GPENCIL',
                     'ARMATURE', 'LATTICE', 'EMPTY',  'CAMERA', 'SPEAKER']

# Select all objects in the scene to be deleted:

for o in Objects:
    if o.type in deleteListObjects:
        o.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete() # Deletes all selected objects in the scene

def auto_dist(target):
    viewAngle=0.691112
    xs=[ p[0] for p in target.bound_box]
    ys=[ p[1] for p in target.bound_box]
    zs=[ p[2] for p in target.bound_box]
    longest=norm([max(xs)-min(xs),max(ys)-min(ys),max(zs)-min(zs)])
    dist=longest/2/tan(viewAngle/2)/cos(viewAngle/2)
    return dist
def setCameraAngle(target=None,phi=0,theta=0):
'''
angle: radius
'''
camera=None
 
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if target is None and o.type=='MESH':
        target=o
    elif o.type=='CAMERA':
        camera=o
if target is None:
    raise ValueError('No mesh')
if camera is None:
    raise ValueError('No camera')
dist=norm([camera.location,[0,0,0]])
camera.location=[dist*cos(theta)*cos(phi),dist*cos(theta)*sin(phi),dist*sin(theta)]
camera.rotation_euler=[0.5*pi-theta,0,0.5*pi+phi]
def presetCompositor():

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
# clear default nodes
for node in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(node)

# create input view node
input_node = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeRLayers')
input_node.location = 0,0

# create output node
convert_space=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeConvertColorSpace')
convert_space.from_color_space='sRGB'
convert_space.to_color_space='Linear'
convert_space.name='convert_space'

#multi_ply3=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
#multi_ply3.operation='MULTIPLY'
#multi_ply3.name='multiply3'

comp_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeComposite')   
comp_node.location = 400,0

# create middle node 
normalize=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeNormalize')
map_range=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMapRange')
map_range.use_clamp=True
map_range.inputs[1].default_value=0
map_range.inputs[2].default_value=2000
map_range.inputs[3].default_value=0
map_range.inputs[4].default_value=2000

less_than1=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
less_than1.operation='LESS_THAN'
less_than1.name='less_than1'
less_than1.inputs[1].default_value=0.99999

less_than2=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
less_than2.operation='LESS_THAN'
less_than2.name='less_than2'
less_than2.inputs[1].default_value=2000

multi_ply1=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
multi_ply1.operation='MULTIPLY'
multi_ply1.name='multiply1'
multi_ply2=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
multi_ply2.operation='MULTIPLY'
multi_ply2.name='multiply2'

divide=tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
divide.operation='DIVIDE'
divide.inputs[1].default_value=65.535

# inner link nodes


links = tree.links

links.new(input_node.outputs[2],normalize.inputs[0])
links.new(normalize.outputs[0], less_than1.inputs[0])
links.new(normalize.outputs[0], multi_ply1.inputs[0])
links.new(less_than1.outputs[0], multi_ply1.inputs[1])


links.new(input_node.outputs[2],map_range.inputs[0])
links.new(map_range.outputs[0], less_than2.inputs[0])
links.new(map_range.outputs[0], divide.inputs[0])
links.new(divide.outputs[0], multi_ply2.inputs[0])
links.new(less_than2.outputs[0], multi_ply2.inputs[1])


#links.new(convert_space.outputs[0],multi_ply3.inputs[0])
#links.new(multi_ply3.outputs[0],comp_node.inputs[0])

links.new(convert_space.outputs[0],comp_node.inputs[0])

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = False
def change_compositor(mode:int=0):
    
    '''
    0:render
    1:normalized depth 
    2:millimeter depth
    '''
    if mode!=0 and mode!=1 and mode!=2:
        '''No Change'''
        return
    if mode==0:
        bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = False
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_mode='RGBA'
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_depth='8'
    elif mode==1:
        bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
        nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
        links = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links
        
        links.new(nodes['multiply1'].outputs[0],nodes['convert_space'].inputs[0])
        #links.new(nodes['less_than1'].outputs[0],nodes['multiply3'].inputs[1])
        
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_mode='BW'
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_depth='16'
    
    elif mode==2:
        bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
        nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
        links = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links
        links.new(nodes['multiply2'].outputs[0],nodes['convert_space'].inputs[0])
        #links.new(nodes['less_than2'].outputs[0],nodes['multiply3'].inputs[1])
        
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_mode='BW'
        Scene.render.image_settings.color_depth='16'


def list_render(anglelist:list[tuple[float]],filepath:str,savedir:str):
    deleteAllObjects()
    ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=filepath)
    fileID=os.path.split(filepath)[1].split('.')[0]
    
    ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for o in Objects:
        if o.type=='MESH':
            o.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active=o
    ops.object.join()
    ops.object.origin_set(type='GEOMETRY_ORIGIN')
    ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    target=None
    for o in Objects:
        if o.type=='MESH':
            target=o
            break
    ops.object.camera_add(location=[auto_dist(target),0,0],rotation=[0.5*pi,0,0.5*pi])
    
    
    
    #settings
    ##Format
    Scene.render.resolution_x = 256            
    Scene.render.resolution_y = 256
    Scene.camera = Objects['Camera'] 
    Scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
    Scene.render.image_settings.compression = 0
    
    
    ##render format
    Scene.render.engine = Engines[1]#Use EEVEE
    
    
    

    
    anglelen=len(anglelist)
    for i in range(anglelen):
        
        
        phi=anglelist[i][0]
        theta=anglelist[i][1]
        setCameraAngle(target,phi,theta)
        prename='view_'+str(i)
        
        #Render main view
        Scene.render.film_transparent = True
        change_compositor(0)
        Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+'.png')
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
        

        change_compositor(1)
        Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+'_depth.png')
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
        

        change_compositor(2)
        Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+'_depth_mm.png')
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
        
        sublist=[
            (phi,theta+pi/18),
            (phi,theta-pi/18),
            (phi+pi/18,theta),
            (phi-pi/18,theta),
        ]
        for j in range(4):
            Phi=sublist[j][0]
            Theta=sublist[j][1]
            setCameraAngle(target,Phi,Theta)
            midname='_'+str(j)+'_10'
            
            change_compositor(0)
            Scene.render.film_transparent = False
            Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+midname+'.png')
            bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
            
            Scene.render.film_transparent = True
            Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+midname+'_gt.png')
            bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )

            change_compositor(2)
            Scene.render.film_transparent = True
            Scene.render.filepath=os.path.join(savedir,fileID,prename+midname+'_gt_depth_mm.png')
            bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
        
        
presetCompositor()
list_render([(pi/4.,pi/4),
             (3*pi/4.,pi/4),
             (5*pi/4.,pi/4),
             (7*pi/4.,pi/4),
             (pi/4.,0),
             (3*pi/4.,0),
             (5*pi/4.,0),
             (7*pi/4.,0),],
            'D:/My Codes/Python3/BlenderPY/shiba.glb',
            'D:/My Codes/Python3/BlenderPY/dogresults',
            )


You are sure the Python code creates the exact same node tree?

Thank you for your reply. Here they are the same tree. In my python code I created 2 node sets. One outputs normalized depth map, the other outputs millimeter depth map. I change using set by changing 2 connections .Both sets have the problem. Here I select the simpler set to show the problem.
